# Обновить форк до апстрима на Gitea

Tags: git, gitea

[image: Скрин Gitea]

Работаем в Gitea (1.15.x). До истерики не могу понять как мне обновить мой форк до состояния основного репозитория (апстрима). На гитхабе есть кнопка "Fetch upstream". Неужели в Gitea нет подобной функции в WebUI?

В апстримном репозитории кнопка "Форкнуть" недоступна, так как форк в моем профиле уже существует. Никаких кнопок найти не могу. Вопрос практически не гуглится и всё, что [нашел](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244321/how-do-i-update-or-sync-a-forked-repository-on-github), это ручной вариант:

```
# Add the remote, call it "upstream":

git remote add upstream https://github.com/whoever/whatever.git

# Fetch all the branches of that remote into remote-tracking branches

git fetch upstream

# Make sure that you're on your master branch:

git checkout master

# Rewrite your master branch so that any commits of yours that
# aren't already in upstream/master are replayed on top of that
# other branch:

git rebase upstream/master
```

Comment: Пробовали создавать pull request для обновления?

Comment: Вообще-то до недавнего времени и на гитхабе не было такой кнопки. Так что в конечном итоге все делалил git pull/git push